# How to query rows from an aggregated and ordered table but skipping the last two rows for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following aggregated table:

```
aid | created    | vid | md5   | an |
-------------------------------------
1   | 2014-05-01 | 1   | <md5> | a  |
2   | 2014-05-01 | 2   | <md5> | s  |
2   | 2014-05-06 | 3   | <md5> | a  |
1   | 2014-05-09 | 4   | <md5> | d  |
1   | 2014-05-09 | 5   | <md5> | g  |
3   | 2014-06-01 | 6   | <md5> | a  |
4   | 2014-06-02 | 7   | <md5> | d  |
4   | 2014-06-02 | 8   | <md5> | s  |
4   | 2014-06-03 | 9   | <md5> | s  |
1   | 2014-06-06 | 10  | <md5> | s  |
```

Source tables:

```
Table name: a
---------------------
aid - INT PK NN UN AI
pn - CHAR(1) NN
...

Table name: v
----------------------
vid - INT PK NN UN AI
aid - NN
created - TIMESTAMP NN (INDEXED)
md5 - CHAR(32) NN (INDEXED)
...
```

I need to create a *MySql* query (MariaDB) that orders the list by `aid, created DESC, vid DESC` and skips the last two rows for each `aid`.

So the result would be:

```
aid | created    | vid | md5
------------------------------
1   | 2014-05-01 | 1  | <md5>
1   | 2014-05-09 | 4   | <md5>
4   | 2014-06-02 | 7   | <md5>
```

My first idea was using LIMIT within IN (...) but I got a "not supported" error message. Then I tried using the [rownum()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) trick but I always got a wrong order (I believe because of the indexes). Now I have no more ideas. Any help would be appreciated!

SQL for 2nd idea:

```
SELECT
    v2.*,
    @rownum:=CASE WHEN @aid=aid THEN @rownum+1 ELSE 1 END AS vorder,
    @appid:=aid AS aid
FROM (
    SELECT aid, created, vid, md5 FROM v ORDER BY aid, created DESC, vid DESC
) AS v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi papaiatis,

```
select * from v a where 
(select count(*) from v b where a.aid = b.aid and a.vid >= b.vid) > 2
order by aid, created desc, vid desc
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But unfortunately I wrongly described my problem. I want to skip the **last** two entries, not the first two! Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: Sure! For each row from the table v I count the number of rows from the same table with smaller or equal vid for the same aid. That will be my auxiliary table b. First aid = 1 with vid = 1 has count = 1, because there is no smaller vid and one equal vid in b. Second aid = 1 has count 2.  I am interested only in rows from v with count > 2 in b. If you want to skip last two rows for each aid you just need to change the condition to a.vid <= b.vid.